# This is the last and Most Evil Save Box Ever

Tags: i-wanna-be-the-guy

After completing the "Final Tower of The Guy", right before the final fight, there is a save box. It is labeled "Evil", so I guess that should tip the player off that something is amiss.

This probably should not come as a big surprise, as frustration and surprise seem to be the rule in this game. Nevertheless, this seems ***unusually*** frustrating, even for a game such as this.

Is there anything that can be done? Or does the player need to traverse the "Final Tower of The Guy" before each attempt at the final boss?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a comment by [Mighty Damo](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCGgF10w71Fjef4R7-3GWovA) on [this page](https://youtu.be/ogD2bzH0v_g?t=3m54s):

> Hey ris,this is really important for you,you have to keep shooting the save block and after you kill it the regular save block comes back.So you can actually save from there.i hope that was good advise.so good luck beating THE GUY!

And here is a video of Let's Play-er Ris Grestar successfully saving before the final boss:

---

*Moral of the story: some YouTube comments are helpful and OK to read [(but most are not)](https://xkcd.com/202/)*